# Permissive CORS during development, restrive CORS on production

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, cors

We are doing cross-site requests to ASP.NET WebApi 2.2. We enabled CORS within `WebApiConfig`:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://www.mydomain.ca", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
    }
}
```

This works well on the LIVE site. During development, we need more permissive CORS settings, because we host both the WebService and the WebClient in IIS from multiple development environments. I.e. we need `new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");` on the development boxes and the restricted origin while LIVE.

How can we automate switching from permissive to restrictive CORS on development and live environments?

Answer (score 0):

Our current approach using the built in `DEBUG` constant and [preprocessor directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx). So long as we run our WebApi project in Debug configuration, we have the permissive CORS settings.

Define Debug:

1. Project > Properties
2. Build
3. Configuration: Debug
4. General > Define DEBUG constant.

Then use the preprocessor directives:

```
#if DEBUG
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
#else
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://www.mydomain.ca","*", "*");
#endif
```

Comment: You could also store the origin values in a config file (or database entry), and have different config files for live vs dev.